# Xcode print stack trace for a crash on third party library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, stack-trace, flurry

I'm using a 3rd party library for my iOS project and there is a crash in that. I need to get a full stack trace on console in order to provide them with information on the crash. I'd like to know if there is a way to get it printed on console or more meaningful way than whats shown in debug-navigator in Xcode ?

I tried few things I could find in previous posts like

- [How to add a breakpoint to objc_exception_throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw)
- [Stack trace or more info on unhandled exception in Xcode/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093999/stack-trace-or-more-info-on-unhandled-exception-in-xcode-iphone)
- [Xcode stack trace not appearing in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960816/xcode-stack-trace-not-appearing-in-console))
- [No exception stacktrace in console under Xcode 4.2/iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5)

But nothing seem to work. The only thing I can get is the screenshot of the debug-navigator window when crash occurs. it's given below.

- [image]

This is the only console log I obtain (all printed from library code)

- [image]

Is there a better way to extract more information on this to send to the library developer ?

`-[FlurryAdViewController removeWindow]`  < This class & method is from the library.

Comment: This is all the info you can get. Just send the output of `bt` command and console output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NSLog() to whatever you get as the error? Try putting the error into the NSLog and it should print that to the console for you to see. Please let me know if I am misconnecting your issue, as I am a bit confused.

Comment: It doesn't point to a place in my code. Hence I cannot use NSLog() or the suggestion given in this post 

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100054/no-exception-stack-trace-in-console-under-xcode-4-2-ios-5  

Its an advertisement library & when you close the ad, app crashes.