# No stacktrace when running xcodebuild

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a strange issue in which a unit test fails only when running tests through the CLI:

```
xcodebuild test -project project.xcodeproj -scheme project -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=15.5'
```

And it fails with:

```
Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but object 0x6000036fe610 was already deallocated
```

Sadly I am using a lot of `unowned` in my code and the test passes when I run it in the GUI (Xcode).

I am wondering if it is possible to get a stacktrace along with the error, because I do not know where to start now. It just says 'Fatal error' without any helpful line number. I won't just change `unowned` to `weak` to make the test pass.

How can I make sure the `xcodebuild` also provides a stacktrace when an error occurs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode stack trace not appearing in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960816/xcode-stack-trace-not-appearing-in-console)

Comment: @lazarevzubov unfortunately not :( that is about the gui, not cli